# Endomorphism of the symmetric group of the set of positive integers via action on the prime numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, prime-numbers, permutations, permutation-groups

For a positive integer $n$, let $p_n$ denote the $n$-th prime number.
Further let $f: {\rm Sym}(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow {\rm Sym}(\mathbb{N})$
be the monomorphism which maps a permutation $\sigma$ to the permutation
$f(\sigma)$ which maps any prime number $p_n$ to $p_{n^\sigma}$ and which is
a homomorphism of the monoid $(\mathbb{N},\cdot)$.

Denoting by $f^{(k)}$ the $k$-fold iteration of $f$, is it true that the
trajectory $(f^{(k)}(\sigma))_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is cyclic only if
$\sigma$ is the identity?

Further, is it even true that
$$\bigcap_{k=0}^\infty f^{(k)}({\rm Sym}(\mathbb{N})) \ = \ 1?$$
If the latter is false, can one explicitly describe a non-identity element
of this intersection?

Comment: What is $n^\sigma$? Should it be $\sigma_n$ or $\sigma(n)$?

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev $n^\sigma$ denotes the *image* of $n$ under $\sigma$.

Comment: Ok, so it's same as $\sigma(n)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\sigma$ is the identity, then so is $f(\sigma)$.

Suppose that $\sigma$ is not the identity. Let $m_k$ be the smallest non-fixed point of $f^{(k)}(\sigma)$. 
It is clear that $m_0\geq 1$ is some finite integer, and for any $k\geq 0$, $m_{k+1} = p_{m_k} > m_k$.
In particular, we have $m_k\geq q_k$, where $q_0=1$ and $q_{i+1}=p_{q_i}$ for $i\geq 0$ ([A007097](https://oeis.org/A007097)).

It follows that the trajectory of $f^{(k)}(\sigma)$ cannot be cyclic unless $\sigma$ is the identity.

Now, for every $k\geq 0$, all elements of $f^{(k)}(\mathrm{Sym}(\mathbb N))$, except the identity, have smallest non-fixed point $\geq q_k$. Hence, the intersection of  $f^{(k)}(\mathrm{Sym}(\mathbb N))$ consists of the identity permutation only.

Comment: @StefanKohl: I'm not sure what is interesting to you. Personally I find it quite interesting that $m_k$ is fully determined by $m_0$ (i.e., the smallest non-fixed point of $\sigma$) and otherwise does not depend on $\sigma$.